# Securing username and password passed as Environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, encryption, passwords, environment-variables

Username and Password are passed as plain text as environment variable while running a bash script from a existing process. using following command.

`sudo -u someuser USERNAME=abc PASSWORD=xyz /path/to/script/bashscript argument1 argument2`

Above bash script is user configurable script with username and password. the challenge I am facing above is, Environment variables are getting logged. like in auth.log which we don't want.

I am looking for ways to achieve one of the following:

1. To prevent it from logging(into auth.log).
2. encrypt username and password in exiting process(c program) and pass as environment variable and have some way to decrypt it in bash script.

I tried looking solution for this. didn't found any which fit with my use-case. Can someone please help me with this? I will also like to know any other ways to make system more secure.

Comment: This may be better asked on security.stackexchange.  Have you considered communicating using a shared file only readable by those users or a named pipe? A fole with credentials seems to be the typical way to handle this.

Comment: See if any of the methods described in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224370/how-to-stop-sudo-pam-messages-in-auth-log-for-a-specific-user) is relevant here.

Comment: @davidgo we don't want to keep it in any file. cause if someone have root access to system also they should not be able to see it. want to keep it in memory. though wrt to current implementation this still be better solution. i will look into this. Thanks

Comment: If someone has root access its game over if the key is at any time unencrypted between processes -- they can dump the memory or do any number of other things to get the key.  To bypass this you need a different paradigm - like public/private key encryption and only handling publuc keys (or maybe an API/token or abstracted user management like SAML or LDAP)

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your reply. solution provide here is configuration file approach to avoid logging in auth.log. In my use case we don't want to permanent stop logging. since these logs are useful when we run script without username/password. we run many instances of this script in regular interval of time. want to not log when we pass username/password using some flag or mechanism at runtime.

Comment: @davidgo yeah i agree providing environment in plain text even though its not get recorded in auth.log it will go in proc. so having root access breaks it. what i am trying to achieve here is, someone having root or debug logs should not be able to accidentally see credentials. this is not full proof. but provides some level of security. 
approaches mentioned by you will need significant amount of infra changes in existing system and could also impact scale. currently our goal is to achieve some level security. which  stops recording it in any logs and also should not be present in file.

Answer (score 0):

According to
[RSyslog Documentation - Filter Conditions](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/filters.html),
you may add a custom string filter for `rsyslog` inside a
filter file as in `/etc/rsyslog.d/anyname.conf`,
by using some identifying string for the logged message for this
command:

```
:msg, contains, "bashscript"       stop
```

See the post
[How to stop sudo PAM messages in auth.log for a specific user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224370/how-to-stop-sudo-pam-messages-in-auth-log-for-a-specific-user)
and especially
[the answer by not2qubit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443367/17660).

(Unfortunately, I'm unable to test it myself.)